# 'ffmpeg' not found? relativ path? install ffmpeg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, path, discord.py

I am making a Discord Music Bot. And to play music I need the following line.

```
ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL,executable="C:/Users/ ....../ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" ,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

The problem is the part with the path (executable="........").
It does work with an absolute path, but I want a relative path, so I can easily transport my program on a stick and give it to other people.

So I tried something to do a relative path like "../ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", but it did not work (I need to go one directory back and then to /ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe). I even moved ffmpeg.exe to the same directory and used the path "./ffmpeg.exe", but it didn't work too.

*I dont know how to properly install ffmpeg either, I just did it somehow, but not I dont know how to do it on other devices.
Maybe anyone can help me with the path?

Comment: From your executable folder, I assume you use windows. I recommend adding ffmpeg.exe to PATH, for that press windows key, then search for path, then hit enter. When you see system properties, you click on environment variables. There you see user variables, now click on PATH and edit and new and browse and browse to folder containing ffmpeg.exe and save it.

Comment: ps you need to relauch cmd or powershell for it to use new path.

Comment: Thank You. But is there a way without creating a path for 'Environment Variables"? Because this makes it more complicated to  use my Programm on another PC, where the Path is not set yet.

Comment: I mean it do work without creating a PATH for Environment Variables when I use "exucutables=..". But it only work with an absolute path :(

Comment: you can get current `PATH` in python with `PATH=os.environ.get("PATH")` then you append your directory containing ffmpeg with `PATH = PATH + ";C:\path\to\ffmpeg"` and then update new `PATH` with `os.environ['PATH'] = PATH`